# No Longer Able to Suspend ... Why?

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, suspend

I used to be able to suspend my Ubuntu 10.04 PC just fine, but a few days ago, suspend stopped working for me.  Does anyone have any idea how I could troubleshoot this?  I've found the log, but I don't see anything that indicates that it failed.  My screen just goes to black but the computer doesn't actually suspend.

Daryl

Answer (score 1):

You should file a bug report using the instructions from the following page:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume

Answer (score 0):

I've heard about that, I think you just had a update. That update would install nvidia 96 and that's what trouble you I think.

Comment: Is that a new driver?  And if so, could I return to the old driver?

Comment: I remembered that I could select my video driver by going into "Hardware Drivers", so I reverted to driver 173 (although I seem to recall that the driver before 96 had another number).  In any case, it's working fine again, so the driver was indeed at fault!